# Get {% page %} object from php on ajax handler

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, twig, octobercms

I'm using OctoberCms and trying to return a page content from an ajax request. For example, when clicking some internal link, i want to get from ajax the page object like the twig `{% page %}`.

```
public function onInternalLink(){
 $href =  post('href');
 return [
        'title'=>'', //here i want {{ page.title }}
        'content' => '', //and here {% page %} like this variable in layout.
             ];
     }
 }
```

my js code is

```
  $.request('onInternalLink', {
       data: {href: u}, // var u is the requested url to return
        success: function() {
            console.log('Almost october');
        }
    })
 }
```

I tried to create new CmsObject and try to use parseMarkup() method, and try pageCycle() with no success.
I didn't find a way to get the `{% page %}` object from the php script, is there way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

in your PHP, you can use `$this->page` to access the current page. So your php would become:

```
public function onInternalLink() {
    $href =  post('href');
    return [
        'title'=> $this->page->title,
        'content' => $this->getContentsFromFile($this->page->baseFileName),
    ];
}
```

All you would need after this would be to write the logic to fetch html content from the baseFileName of the page (I have wrapped this as $this->getContentsFromFile() in the example above).

There are more variables provided by `$this-> page` - Read about them here -  https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/pages#page-variables